# Approval Flow in power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a Leave Request SharePoint list which has below columns:

Name (Person or Group)

Team (Choice)

Type Of Leave (Choice)

From (Date & Time)

To (Date & Time)

Half Day (Yes/No)

AM or PM (Choice)

Number Of Days (Number)

Number Of Hours (Number)

The approval flow for all the teams is different. The first approval goes to their respective Team Leads and if approved then the second approval will go to the manager.

I have already created a flow which triggers the right approval.

When an item is created -----> Initialize variable (string, Team value)-----> Switch (Add teams as cases... ServiceDesk, Incident, etc)-----> (FOR ALL THE TEAMS) Start and wait for approval----->Condition--->If Yes(Approved)------->Start and wait for approval 2.

The flow is working fine and triggers the right approval.

Now, I have a condition that if the "Type of Leave" is "Time Off" then the approval will go only to the respective team leads and not to the manager which means only one approval needed but different approvals for each teams. Now how can i add this condition to my flow ?

I tried but the initialize variable which i created for Team switch cannot be after a condition which means it has to be on the top.

Sorry I am not a technical person so this is a bit confusing for me.

Any help and guidance will be much appreciated.

Thank You.
Niki.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another row to your condition.

So your Condition would be something like

> ```
> Approval Status is equal to "Approved"
> ```
>
> **AND**
>
> ```
> Leave Type is NOT equal to "Time Off"
> ```
>
> Yes = Start and wait for approval 2
>
> No = Something else

Comment: Hi.... Thank You for your time and solution. I tried the above solution but its still triggering the second approval

Comment: Can i add another action as a condition?